# Backbone.js - Destroying a Marionette Controller

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm having issues destroying a Marionette controller. I'm still wrapping my brains around Marionette, and more specifically Backbone garbage collection....

This controller instantiates several views, each of which may have several bound event listeners. The code looks something like this:

```
myController.js
---------------
Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');
MyView     = require('path/to/myView');

var MyController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        console.log('init');
    }
    onDestroy: function() {
        console.log('should be destroyed');
    }
    showData: function() {
        console.log('create view');
        myView = new MyView();
    }
});



appController.js
----------------
MyController = require('path/to/myController');

var controller = new MyController()
controller.showData();
controller.destroy();


output:
//init
//create view
//should be destroyed
```

Controller is still around, even though onDestroy does fire..

Could this be an issue with views still having bound event listeners? My apologies if the code looks weird... translating this from coffeescript.

Answer (score 1):

To call the destroy method, the Marionette controller has a "close" method defined on its prototype:

```
controller.close();
```

The method that is called is `onClose`.

For info, you can check this in the console:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed it to controller.close(), which indeed closes it, but its still in memory when doing a heap snapshot..

Comment: Are there perhaps some lingering event listeners in the controller? If you use "on", then call "off" in the onClose method. When using listenTo, you can use stopListening. Other than that, the object should be cleaned up. When the cleanup happens exactly is a decision of the garbage collector, but normally you can perform a manual cleanup as well. (In Chrome it's the recycle bin icon).

Comment: Well, the controller itself doesn't have any event listeners, but some of the many views that this controller creates use this.listenTo... I've been having issues destroying one of these views, which I think is probably the real issue here. Should I explicitly say onClose -> this.stopListening() on all of the views this controller is creating?

Comment: In Marionette you usually use regions to display and close down views (either through layouts or on the fly), which afaik will call stopListening automatically. What I tend to do is to instantiate regions in the initialize method of the controller, and call `this.region.close()` in the `onClose` method of the controller.

Comment: We're also using regions. In this case, this one controller sets up 3 views, each with their own region. So all three regions get passed into the controller, then the controller has a method for each of the three views it needs to create (along with other logic) which get their respective region passed. All this during init.

Comment: That's fine. Just think about closing the regions when you don't need them anymore or I believe that the views won't get cleaned up.

Comment: which marionette version are we talking about? the close and destroy api changed in the meantime. there's no close method any longer in the current version.
This might help:
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md#destroying-a-controller

Comment: @AchimKoellner You are right; I noticed that I use an older version. The destroy method should work just as good in the newer version.